# Mac won't boot Windows partition after using disk utility

Tags: mac, bootcamp, windows, partition

I needed more space on my Windows partition... So I used *Disk Utility* to free up some space from the OS X partition, and upon restarting to Windows in order to add the free space to windows, I discovered that windows no longer boots! OS X still boots, but how can I fix my Windows partition without reinstalling Windows and losing all my data?

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` and `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` to your question.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me.  I have macOS 10.12.3 and Windows 10.

1. Boot to Recovery mode (restart, hold "command+R")
2. Utilities -> terminal
3. Run

   ```
   fdisk -e /dev/disk0"
   p
   setpid 4
   [press enter]
   flag 4
   p
   write
   y
   ```
4. Reboot

Answer (score 1):

The Terminal commands below has been proven to work in this situation. It's a fix within the last year from someone with the same problem. Disk Utility and Boot Camp were never designed to cooperate. Unfortunately, they aren't labelled at all to prevent this kind of event from taking place.

For future reference, I believe the way to resize the partition is to do so in Boot Camp Assistant. Since you already did it, however, you'll need to adjust your partition manually in order to get it booting again. Of course, replace disk0 with your disk number which you can find in Disk Utility.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6465316

> ```
> sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk0
> p
> setpid 4
> 07
> flag 4
> p
> write
> y
> ```
>
> Now Reboot and hold the ALT key and check if Windows shows up and is
>   bootable.   If you get 'missing operating system', then Windows
>   Startup Repair and see if Windows will comeback alive.   If you notice
>   the difference between the Disk Utility screen (two partitions) vs the
>   fdisk output (or the GPT) there are 'hidden' partitions and the MBR
>   partitioning style used for Windows allows a maximum of 4 partitions.
>   If you need further explanation, read the original thread.   Yosemite
>   should not be installed on any machine that is critical to you. If
>   only partitioning was done, but Yosemite was NOT installed, you are in
>   better shape. Yosemite ignores and is unaware of bootcamp and creates
>   an additional Recovery HD and moves things around.

Comment: there seems to be nothing there when typing p in the second step. #1 shows data but 2-4 are empty. My files still exist because I can still access them.

Comment: Before I address that, I just had the thought that you may be able to simply open Boot Camp Assistant and repair it that way. Have you tried that?

Comment: "The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition"

Comment: Must be formatted as a single Mac or OS X extended volume or already partitioned by boot camp assistant for installing windows

Comment: The only option I have after that message is to create an install disk...

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to do that. It's hard for me to know why p didn't give you any output without seeing what happened after your first command. Could you paste what you see after typing the first line in Terminal?