# Problem when extending windows partition using Disk Utility

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I tried to partitioning the macOS partition to have some space to extend the Windows partition using Windows OS. When trying to switch back to Windows OS, I could not find it. Even when restarting and pressing down the Option key. I found a thread with the same problem and its solution. But when trying the solution, I had a problem. The solution was entering this code in the terminal in recovery mode:

```
fdisk -e /dev/disk0s4
p
setpid 4
[press enter]
flag 4
p
write
y
```

> disk0s4 is the partition with the windows on It.

But when trying to type the first line, I received an error saying "Resource is busy".

My software is MacOS High Sierra.

If there is any help, I would be grateful.

Notes:
The link of the thread is [Mac won't boot Windows partition after using disk utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217527/mac-wont-boot-windows-partition-after-using-disk-utility/217528).
Mac version is Macbook mid 2010.
And the Windows is Windows 7.
This was the output when executing the command `diskutil list disk0` in the terminal:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS macOS                   124.0 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
4:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows OS              125.2 GB   disk0s4
```

And the output from `fdisk /dev/disk0` is

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 30401/255/63 [488397168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
     Starting       Ending
#: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  488397167] <Unknown ID>
2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Below is the output from `diskutil info disk0s4`.

```
Device Identifier: disk0s4 
Device Node: /dev/disk0s4 
Whole: No 
Part of Whole: disk0 

Volume Name: Windows OS 
Mounted: Yes 
Mount Point: /Volumes/Windows OS 

Partition Type: Microsoft Basic Data 
File System Personality: NTFS 
Type (Bundle): ntfs 
Name (User Visible): Windows NT File System (NTFS) 

OS Can Be Installed: No 
Media Type: Generic 
Protocol: SATA 
SMART Status: Verified 
Volume UUID: FA34FC24-AD79-47B7-BF7F-20928229DB81 
Disk / Partition UUID: B94B94F6-3041-44DB-AFD6-37465DCC16B1 
Partition Offset: 124860235776 Bytes (243867648 512-Byte-Device-Blocks) 

Disk Size: 125.2 GB (125197877248 Bytes) (exactly 244527104 512-Byte-Units) 
Device Block Size: 512 Bytes 

Volume Total Space: 125.2 GB (125197873152 Bytes) (exactly 244527096 512-Byte-Units) 
Volume Used Space: 67.1 GB (67050299392 Bytes) (exactly 130957616 512-Byte-Units) (53.6%) 
Volume Free Space: 58.1 GB (58147573760 Bytes) (exactly 113569480 512-Byte-Units) (46.4%) 
Allocation Block Size: 4096 Bytes 

Read-Only Media: No 
Read-Only Volume: Yes 

Device Location: Internal 
Removable Media: Fixed 

Solid State: No 
Hardware AES Support: No
```

Comment: I edited the post @DavidAnderson

Comment: @Sam So, can I use it to repair my booting problem?

Comment: Probably? I think that it fixed mine a while ago

Comment: maybe add the output from `diskutil info disk0s5` instead of from `diskutil list`

Comment: oops, you’re looking for the tuxera tool to repair windows

Comment: Eventually, I removed the windows and Installed It again. However, Thank you, guys.

Comment: Well, that's one way to do it. Next time, try using Paragon Camptune (I'll add a link later)

Comment: @Sam: Maybe you could answer [this question.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352567/resize-system-partition)

Comment: ty @DavidAnderson

Answer (score 2):

Use Hard Disk Manager to repair and partition BOOTCAMP.

You can get Hard Disk Manager from here (https://www.paragon-software.com/hdm-mac/#) or here (includes trial reset) (https://nofile.io/f/aWdNwtb3Ry9/Hard.Disk.Manager.v1.3.873.dmg) (link will expire in 24 hrs)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, bro. but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try repartitioning or repairing it first

Comment: I didn't find `Update Bootcamp MBR...`

Comment: When you push “actions” on your windows partition?

Comment: All I got for Bootcamp is ‘Correct Bootcamp Boot Records’..

Comment: Did you run that?

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing changed.

Comment: Are you trying to reboot after you try this stuff?

Comment: And is it booting or you can’t find the partition when booting holding option?

Comment: I didn't find the partition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90185/discussion-between-maher-farghaly-and-sam).