# Resize system partition?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, mojave

I found some questions like that here but it doesn't help me.  I use Paragon hard disk manager & disk utility to resize it and have screenshot like below.

But I can't add free space to main osx partition. I found that I have to move free space section to near main partition so I can able to resize it.

So how do I do that?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Whatever you do, dont resize it from the windows side, it will break your mac partition :D ...found that out the hard way...

Comment: @Vladimir what exactly happened? Camptune on my Mac is stuck on “Resizing volumes, this may take a while...” for 9 hours now.

Comment: @brown1001 My mac had encription turned on, and while I was using bootcamp, I decided to split the windows partition so I could also install linux. Doing so was a horrible mistake. It somehow wiped out the part of my master boot record responsible for encryption/decryption, and I lost all of my data. Years, of photos and videos etc. It was terrible. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't even start this without a solid backup.

Right click the NTFS partition & select Move/Resize Partition.
Drag the Free Space After slider all the way to the left.
This will move the NTFS partition to the end of the disk & the free space into the area outlined below, between the APFS container & NTFS partition. This should then consolidate your free space.

[image]

Volumes on APFS containers will not show as filling all the available space, due to their 'live expandability' feature, even though the container itself does. I don't have an example with APFS & NTFS to show, but this is my 1TB SSD which shows as having 456GB 'free' at the end whereas the container itself & in the Finder the Volume is actually [almost] the entire 1TB.

[image]

So, to complete your changes, you need to select the APFS Container [not the Volume on it] & again using Move/Resize Partition, change the New Size until it fills your moved Free Space.

[image]

Remember to Apply Operations afterwards.

Note: This is likely to be a very long, slow operation; whilst potentially a lot faster on SSD [on which I have never actually tried to do a data move of this size] on HD I'd expect to come back to it in the morning, so make sure you have plenty of time & keep the Mac on mains power.

Comment: This is exactly what I need to do, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped. Remember to mark the answer as accepted using the check-mark near the top of the answer if you feel it warrants it. [I don't need the points, but it helps later Googlers if there's an accepted answer.]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my computer working to follow along with my answer right now, but I'll try to do this from memory.

There are three sliders:

1. Free space before
2. Size of partition
3. Free space after

When they say free space before and after, they aren't referring to before and after the operation, they are referring to *before* and *after* the selected partition.

**Important!** Try the solution that I put at the bottom of the answer first, if it works it'll be the lease messy solution.

It looks like you want to have 50gb of free space *before*, so (I think) delete the free space partition, and then either:

1. increase the size of the apple one directly (not sure if this can be done)
2. select the mac and windows partition (I'm presuming that the 50gb came from there) and adjust them how you want (again, not sure if this can be done)

**Or**, (this can probably be done) don't delete the 50gb free space partition, and just drag it to the left. I don't know off of the top of my head how to merge partitions, but with the free space next to it, it will probably just let you increase the partition size. To do this though, you have to be looking at the size adjustments for the macOS partition, not the free space one or the windows one.

Comment: I'd feel very uncomfortable making sweeping guesses with someone else's data. You cannot 'delete' free space, it's already free space. You need to move the NTFS volume to shift the location of the free space then resize the the APFS container [not the Mac volume] to fill it.