# 80 gb missing "free space" after deleting bootcamp - resizing container leads to error 69716

Tags: disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

(Update to the previously closed question: this is a frequent issue. In a previous post, I was linked to a similar question which suggested to resize the container. However, this does not address the issue in my case. Resizing leads to error with associated dstream id objects)

I deleted Bootcamp but an error occurred that the free space could not be restored to the existing partition. Now I am stuck with 80 GB of "free space" which I cannot add to my standard partition. I have tried repairing with disk utility - no action taken - as well as removing the "free space" - but errors occur.

Here is a screenshot of my `diskutil list`.

```
Nilss-MBP:~ nils$ diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
       1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
       2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         418.0 GB   disk0s2
                        (free space)                         82.0 GB    -
    
    /dev/disk1 (synthesized):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +418.0 GB   disk1
                                     Physical Store disk0s2
       1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Daten⁩    339.1 GB   disk1s1
       2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 471.6 MB   disk1s2
       3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s3
       4:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.4 GB    disk1s4
       5:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.4 GB    disk1s4s1
       6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk1s5
```

Here is part of the output when trying to resize the container, indicating what seems to go awry in my case:

```
Nilss-MBP:~ nils$ sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0

Checking snapshot 1 of 2 (com.apple.TimeMachine.2022-08-03-114336.local) error: dstream (id 3281843) does not have an associated dstream id object  
warning: snapshot fsroot / file key rolling / doc-id tree corruptions are not repaired; they'll go away once the snapshot is deleted  
error: alloced_size (86016) of dstream (id 3281843) does not match calculated size (0)  
error: dstream (id 3286987) does not have an associated dstream id object  
error: alloced_size (16384) of dstream (id 3286987) does not match calculated size (0)  
error: dstream (id 14693189) does not have an associated dstream id object  
error: alloced_size (1884160) of dstream (id 14693189) does not match calculated size (0)  
error: dstream (id 14910577) does not have an associated dstream id object  
error: alloced_size (1110016) of dstream (id 14910577) does not match calculated size (0)  
Checking snapshot 2 of 2 (com.apple.TimeMachine.2022-08-03-124315.local)  
error: dstream (id 3281843) does not have an associated dstream id object  
(// similar errors as with snapshot 1)  
Checking the document ID tree  
Checking the fsroot tree  
error: refcnt (1) of dstream id object (id 3281843) is less than expected (2)  
error: dstream (id 3286987) does not have an associated dstream id object  
(// more, similar errors as with snapshots 1 and 2)   
Checking the extent ref tree  
Verifying volume object map space  
The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired  
Performing deferred repairs  
error: refcnt of dstream id object (id 3281843) less than expected  
error: dstream (id 3286987) does not have an associated dstream id object  
Skipped 6/6 repairs of this type in total  
Deferred repairs skipped  
The container /dev/disk0s2 could not be verified completely  
Storage system check exit code is 8  
Error: -69716: Storage system verify or repair failed
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize system partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352567/resize-system-partition)

Comment: A partition is basically fixed size, there are ways to resize partitions (especially if they are adjacent) but the simplest fix might be to make the space available as a new empty partition.

Comment: You just need to enter the command `sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thank you! Unfortunately, this does not solve it for me I think. I am adding the output to my original question. I get the error "Storage system verify or repair failed". The first error when running the command is "Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking snapshot 1 of 2 (com.apple.TimeMachine.2022-08-03-114336.local)
error: dstream (id 3281843) does not have an associated dstream id object". Any idea what to do in this case?

Comment: If your system can boot, it’s time to make a backup using Time Machine or another method you can feel supported in doing a restore. I would not try to adjust things until the file system is without errors.

Comment: Nils: Most likely there was a problem with the APFS Volume ⁨`Macintosh HD - Daten⁩` before you removed Windows. You just became aware when the Windows (Boot Camp) partition was removed. At this point, you should probably make a backup to a another drive first, before attempting any repairs. However, I would recommend erasing the entire drive, then restoring.