# Can't create new partition (to increase windows partition size): internal error

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I need to add some space to my Windows partition without erasing it. macOS Mojave, 10.14.6.

According to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WRkeL1Lnq8) I was going to create a partition using Disk Utility, and then erase it and join with windows partition using MiniTool Partition Wizard.

I'm stuck on the 1st step: I can't create a partition. It shows me an "Internal error" without any details. I tried to do it on **Mc OS X**, **Container disk1**, and **ST3500418AS Media** levels, the same result - internal error.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to fix it? Or is there another way to increase my windows partition size without erasing it?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the result of terminal command : ``diskutil list ``?

Comment: Can you post the version of Windows and the model/year of your Mac?

Comment: I posted an answer to the question [Can not boot into Windows 10 with Boot Camp after partitioning more space to Windows in Disk Utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386945/can-not-boot-into-windows-10-with-boot-camp-after-partitioning-more-space-to-win) where I stated a previous video by John Shirley was fraudulent. I would not be surprised if the video you viewed is also fraudulent.